# How to prove convergence? $Y_n= X_{n+1}-X_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{X_n\}$  be a sequence of real numbers and let  $Y_n= X_{n+1}-X_n$, then $\{Y_n\}$  converges if and only if the sequence $\{X_n\}$ converges.

Comment: Difficult to prove "only if"

Comment: $\sum_1^NY_n=X_{N+1}-X_0$. Now think what it means for $\sum Y_n$ to converge and for $X_n$ to converge.

Comment: Did you want to write "the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Y_n$ converges" instead of "$\{Y_n\}$ converges?

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence $X_n = n$. Then $\{X_n\}$ does not converge, but $\{Y_n\}$ does as $Y_n = 1\forall n$, this is a contradiction to what you want to prove.